# Synthax to declare urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm not sure to understand the difference between the two urls below

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from main_app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='home'),
    (r'^accounts/$', views.accounts, name="account"),
   ...
)
```

Both are working for me. Should I use one instead of the other? Why? All the examples I quickly found were reffering to the first synthax but I'd like to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first syntax, using the url function, allows you to pass a dictionary of keyword arguments to your view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions

From the documentation:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'year_archive', {'foo': 'bar'}),
)
```

In this example, for a request to */blog/2005/*, Django will call

```
blog.views.year_archive(request, year='2005', foo='bar')
```

Comment: So, when no arguments are provided, both method are equivalent or one should be prefeared? Is there a standard here?

Comment: yes, both are equivalent if no additional arguments are provided. There is really no preferred way to do it; just try to be consistent. I'd personally like to use the url() function so I don't mix both ways to do it

Answer (score 2):

This is the latest example from the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) for the urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)
```

So you could say this is the standard as most people will learn it that way and it seems it is also promoted this way.